# wordpress is_tag function not working as expected

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

Objective: if the page being displayed is an archive page for a tag (any tag), display a different line of content in the sidebar.

Note that I am not using this to detect specific tags. I want it to return TRUE if i'm looking at a tag-based archive page, and FALSE if I'm viewing a category archive page, date archive page, post page, the home page, or anything else.

environment: WAMP (using XAMPP) with (PHP 5.4.4) running Wordpress 3.4.2

Code:

```
<?php if (is_tag()) : ?>
--some html--
<?php else: ?>
--other html--
<?php endif; ?>
```

Result:
Navigating to [blog address]/tag/horror/ always shows "--other html--"

I was pretty sure this was the syntax.

Comment: Are you sure that's not something you want to report as a bug?

Comment: it very well may be. I was posting it out here to see if anyone could identify something I did wrong. -- I find that most of the time when I find myself complaining about software or coding it's because I did something slightly wrong.

Comment: Where is the code containing the `is_tag()` function? Theme template file? Plugin? Where specifically?

Answer (score 0):

Would `is_tax()` work for you? http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_tax

Otherwise, could you use a tag template instead?
http://codex.wordpress.org/Tag_Templates

A solution might be to use `get_template_part` http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_template_part

To modularize your template pages, and recycle your loops etc.

Comment: it's a standard tag assigned to the post at writing, so is_tag should work. For giggles I changed is_tag to is_tax and predictably, I got the same behavior. I'm not sure tag templates are what I really want here.